# navigationControllerの任意の画面への遷移

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uinavigationcontroller

日記アプリを作っている初心者です。

現在、写真を複数選択できるImagePicker機能を作っています。
そこで実装したい画面遷移がLINEアプリのように、テキスト入力画面からカメラボタンを押すと、すべての写真が表示され、画面左上の戻るボタンを押すとアルバムの選択画面になるというものです。

説明が下手なので、やりたいことを図にすると以下です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この場合、テキスト入力画面から self.presentViewController()で写真選択画面に遷移すると、ナビゲーションバーが表示されず、うまくいきませんでした。

どのようにすれば実装できるのでしょうか。

Comment: @quesera2 さま
おかげでうまくいきました！
本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController`の`viewControllers`プロパティを使います。

例えば、以下のようなコードになると思います。

```
let albumSelection = AlbumSelectionViewController()
let photoSelection = PhotoSelectionViewController()
let navigation = UINavigationController()
navigation.viewControllers = [albumSelection, photoSelection]
self.presentViewController(navigation, animated: true, completion:nil)
```